# How to use a parameterized query with "GO" statements in .NET?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am using ASP.NET as a backend to an application to update some data in a separate system's SQL Server.

I have a query that needs to insert many rows to a table. In each row, the values being inserted are derived from parameters. To protect against SQL injection attacks, I previously used the SqlCommand object and added parameters like so:

```cs
string query = @"
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 10, @value1);
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 15, @value2);
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 20, @value3);
    ...
";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["context"].ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sql_command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
    sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", value1);
    sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", value2);
    sql_command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", value3);
    ...
    sql_command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This worked well, but for concurrency's sake I would like to execute these in a batch using SQL's "GO" statement. This way, the inserts could not be interrupted by another process locking access to this table. Since SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery does not support the "GO" statement, I decided to look into ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery instead (from Microsoft's SQL Management Objects package). This was promising, as it supports "GO" statements, but I can't find a way to add parameters to my query when executing. According to [Microsoft's docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-common-serverconnection-executenonquery(system-string)), the only parameters allowed for the ExecuteNonQuery method do not contain a parameter list.

Does anyone know how I can achieve this goal? Is it necessary that I use the "GO" statement? Or is there another way of achieving this kind of "batched" execution with the standard SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery?

Comment: It's not that `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't support `GO`. SQL Server itself doesn't know what `GO` means. It's a batch separator that sqlcmd and SSMS define, and only those tools (and maybe tools that seek to be compatible with them) support it *by inclusion*. You can tell SSMS to use something else, like `PROCEED` (Options > Query Execution: Batch Separator), and then even SSMS wouldn't know what `GO` means.

Comment: Put another way: `GO` is **not actually part of the SQL language**. Rather, it's a (common) supplemental feature supported by certain tools.

Comment: Current SqlServer versions allow multiple rows to be inserted in [one statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#b-inserting-multiple-rows-of-data) so you might not need batching capabilities for that.

Comment: `This worked well, but for concurrency's sake I would like to execute these in a batch using SQL's "GO" statement. This way, the inserts could not be interrupted by another process locking access to this table` this sounds very fishy, why would batch in any way help against concurrent locks. If anything, it's probably make things worse because you'll be fighting against your own inserts. I suggest forgoing SQLCommand and use SQLServerBulkInsert or whatever the class is called, it will beat most of these solutions.

Comment: Almost certainly will make things worse. Simple inserts as a rule don't often cause blocking or deadlocks, unless you are deleting/updating out of order. If you want to insert at speed then use `SqlBulkCopy`. This whole question is a complete XY, the perceived problem isn't actually a problem, and the proposed solution is going to make things worse.

Answer (score 3):

`GO` is **not actually part of the SQL language**. Rather, it's a feature commonly supported among various development tools. Sometimes you can even change it to a different word.

Worse, even when you use it, **it's not going to improve concurrency for this operation**.

What you can do is manage the concurrency in your app. So if the values came from a List/IEnumerable, you could do something like this extremely naïve example:

```cs
public async void InsertRecords(int id, IEnumerable<string> valuesToInsert)
{
    // setup query to use batches of size n
    string query = @"
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 10, @value1);
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 15, @value2);
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, 20, @value3);
        ...
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value) VALUES (@id, N*5, @valueN);
    ";
    
    var batches = valuesToInsert.Chunk({your batch size here});
    var tasks = batches.Select(async b => {
        using var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["context"].ConnectionString);
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    
        // AVOID ADDWITHVALUE()!
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        for(int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            // making up the parameter type. Use what's actually in the DB!
            cmd.Parameters.Add($"@value{i+1}", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = b[i];
        }
    
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    });
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

#### BUT!

Even with this, a set of inserts to the same table will probably cause database locking in a way that forces this to be a serial operation! It also leaves you open to a partial success/failure for the operation, making rollbacks and troubleshooting more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Following Ralf's suggestion, I edited the insert to look like the following. Sometimes I guess we can just overthink these things :)

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[table_name] (id, type, value)
VALUES (@id, 10, @value1), (@id, 15, @value2), (@id, 20, @value3) ...;
```